# A simple calculated control in Access to sum up the items from groups

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns

I am a middle school student who's exploring database basics with Access. Here's the problem I encountered:

I am creating a report that calculate the number of balls that each person owns. With grouping and sorting I can manage to display the total number of balls everyone has at the footer of each group, yet in the footer of the report I am supposed to calculate the total number of balls that are out there, what kind of expression should I use?

As to calculate the balls for each person, I utilised this expression:

> =Count(*) & " owned by" & " " & [PlayerName]

In order to produce the result of the number of total balls, what should I do?

The final output is something briefly like:

`PlayerName   BallType`

```
Mark       Blue
           1 owned by Mark

Terry      Red
           1 owned by Terry



Kenny      Blue
           Red
           2 owned by Kenny
```

... ...

> Total num of balls owned by players: __

Thanks for any assistance!
Please note that the "Sum" expression is not allowed with this question :)

Answer (score 0):

=Count(*) in the report footer

Comment: I tried that before but it simply counts the total number of groups, are you sure this works? thanks a lot bro!